# How to update data from database but without updating image in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi guys I have a code here wherein I have to select an image but what if I don't want to update the existing image in my database?
It is an update to a profile in my system.

I am using mysql database and mysqli prepared statement
Could you help me?

Here is my working code.

```
<?php
$id_alum = $_GET['id'];
include('db/database_configuration.php');
if(ISSET($_POST['save'])){

    if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "featured_image/". $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $location = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    //edit.....get input values
    if (empty($_POST['fullname'])){$fullname = 'NULL'; } else{ $fullname ="". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fullname']) . "";}
    if (empty($_POST['job'])){$job_title = 'NULL'; } else{ $job_title ="". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['job']) . "";}
    if (empty($_POST['desc'])){$description = 'NULL'; } else{ $description ="". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['desc']) . "";}
    if (empty($_POST['desc2'])){$description2 = 'NULL'; } else{ $description2 ="". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['desc2']) . "";}

    $sql = "UPDATE `tblfeatured` SET image1=?, fullname=?, job_title=?, description=?, description2=? WHERE id_alum= $id_alum";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // This assumes the date and account_id parameters are integers `d` and the rest are strings `s`
    // So that's 5 consecutive string params and then 4 integer params

    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $location, $fullname, $job_title, $description, $description2);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->errno) {
      echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Updated Successfully')</script>";
        echo '<script>window.location = "featured_result.php"</script>';
    }

    $stmt->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my html file

```
<form method = "POST" action = "update_featured_alumni.php?id=<?php echo $id_alum; ?>" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <label style="color: white; font-size: 12pt;">Change Image? Drag or click for an image</label>

        <div id="uploader" onclick="$('#photo').click()">
        <img src="" width="" />
        <div class="pull-right">Existing Image<img src="featured_image/<?php echo $image;?>" width="150" height="150"></div>
        </div>


        <input type="file" name="image"  id="photo"/>
        <div id = "file_name" style="color: white;"></div>
        <button class = "w3-btn w3-green w3-card-4" name = "save" title="Save"><font size="2"><span class = "fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></span> Save</font></button>

        <br>
        <font color="black">
        <input class = "form-control" type = "text" name= "fullname" placeholder = "Fullname" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" value="<?php echo $fname;?>">



        <input class = "form-control" type = "text" name= "job" placeholder = "Job Title & Workplace" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" value="<?php echo $job;?>">
        <textarea id="txtArea" name="desc" onkeyup="resizeTextarea('txtArea')" data-resizable="true" placeholder="Alumni Description"><?php echo str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $desc); ?></textarea>
        <textarea id="txtArea2" name="desc2" onkeyup="resizeTextarea('txtArea2')" data-resizable="true" placeholder="Alumni Description"><?php echo str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $desc2); ?></textarea>
        </font>
        <button class = "w3-btn w3-green w3-card-4" name = "save" title="Save"><font size="6"><span class = "fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></span> Save</font></button>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want here??

Comment: @OmarElDon mmm. If I don't select an image the image from the database is still the existing image.

Comment: You are updating data only if image file is selected `if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){`. Then why you don't want to update image

Comment: Remove "image1" field

Comment: @B.Desai What if I don't want to update the image? Because there are other contents that can be updated.

Comment: @RahulPrajapati why would I remove image1 field?

Comment: @sauce do you know what technical word "update", "read", "delete" or any equivalents mean... How can you update the database from the database? you question is confusing, try to make it better

Comment: @RahulPrajapati I've clearly stated that 'What if' is there any way?

Comment: @OmarElDon hello ! the question is update data from the database, not database from the database.

Comment: "image1" field update image  so

Comment: @sauce don't be offended by our question, we ask them to help you, that's first, second, what is this data

Comment: please add if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){} for update image if you want

Comment: @OmarElDon I'm not offended. So I've got a full name, job_title, description, description2 and the image. So the question is what if I update the fullname,job title, description and description without updating the image?.

Comment: @RahulPrajapati i've already that

Comment: @sauce that was great of you, i love having understanding people around here, else one person would get down votes for nothing.... any way, the accepted answer seems to be missing one point, a little verification, if user has chosen an image by mistake?? so add a checkbox which will tell if one wants to edit the photo or not so there are no mistakes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$id_alum = $_GET['id'];
include('db/database_configuration.php');
if(ISSET($_POST['save'])){
    $sql_img = "";

    if($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0){
      $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
      $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
      $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "featured_image/". $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
      $location = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
      $location_db = addslashes($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
      $sql_img = "image1 = '".$location."', ";
    }
    //edit.....get input values
    if (empty($_POST['fullname'])){$fullname = 'NULL'; } else{ $fullname ="". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fullname']) . "";}
    if (empty($_POST['job'])){$job_title = 'NULL'; } else{ $job_title ="". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['job']) . "";}
    if (empty($_POST['desc'])){$description = 'NULL'; } else{ $description ="". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['desc']) . "";}
    if (empty($_POST['desc2'])){$description2 = 'NULL'; } else{ $description2 ="". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['desc2']) . "";}
    $sql = "UPDATE `tblfeatured` SET ".$sql_img."fullname=?, job_title=?, description=?, description2=? WHERE id_alum= $id_alum";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // This assumes the date and account_id parameters are integers `d` and the rest are strings `s`
    // So that's 5 consecutive string params and then 4 integer params

    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $fullname, $job_title, $description, $description2);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->errno) {
      echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Updated Successfully')</script>";
        echo '<script>window.location = "featured_result.php"</script>';
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

To explain what i added in simple words: $sql_img that is initially set to empty. If an image is posted, it changes to the image location string. And gets added to the final sql script

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: @sauce try again? i edited the code there was a mistake

Comment: :( it's still the same

Comment: i edited it again, there is no way it doesnt work. Can you check with the new code?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Comment: `bind_param('ssss', $fullname ...` set it to this. sorry didnt notice, posting answers from phone

Comment: it blanks the image field in the database

Comment: @sauce i should stop using stack on my phone. Really sorry for rewriting the code 23123 times. copy it now and check please, there was another bug that i just fixed

Comment: yea you must stop using in your phone but in pc :) Thank you it worked.